# How to configure HA iSCSI for Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, high-availability, zfs

**BACKGROUND:**
We have a StarWind NAS that we are currently using for High Availability storage with our Windows network.  Starwind has mirrored drives and multiple ip paths, that the Windows Server combines into one HA disk store.

**QUESTION:**
How do I accomplish the same thing under Solaris 10?

I've looked at ZFS but to document seems to indicate that ZFS wants to do its own raid/mirroring.

I can also attach via iSCSI from Solaris and am presented with both drives being served by the Starwind NS.

So, how do I configure solaris so that disk M1 and M2 are considered as a single fault tolerant drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found here:

[solaris-10-with-mpxio-scsi-vhc](http://southbrain.com/south/2008/02/solaris-10-with-mpxio-scsi-vhc.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look at DRBD port to Solaris. But nothing compares to StarWind as neither DRBD for Linux nor HAST for FreeBSD combine multi node cluster, LVM, Cache Manager and iSCSI target stack into a single product.